# How to set Minecraft Bedrock version using AMP server hosting

Tags: minecraft, version

I am an admin of a Minecraft Bedrock server that uses AMP as its host. The server's version was recently updated, but now I've learned that it needs to be downgraded. Is this possible from AMP's Minecraft server configuration settings?

Comment: What exactly is the “AMP console”? Difficult to research the subject.

Comment: Sorry; that's poor wording on my part. I'm simply asking whether it's possible from the configuration settings of a particular instance/server. I'll update the OP with this info.

Comment: What does AMP stand for exactly? It’s either a software project or the name of the VPS company.

Comment: @Ramhound [This](https://cubecoders.com/AMP) is what I'm referring to. I'm wondering if there's a specific file or setting I need to change.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of playing around with the server settings, it seems I was able to resolve this by first selecting "Specific version" in the "Release Stream" section:

[image: Release stream settings for AMP]

Then, I clicked the "Download / Update" button in the "Server Type" section:
[image: Download / Update button]